# What are this chips marked "0B2004ZCP" & "0B2603CP"?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, markings, usb-pd

I'm trying to find datasheet for two chips. I found this inside a TCL 18W Quick Charge adapter. I think this are ON Semi parts. But I'm not sure. I think 0B2004ZCP is some kind of diode and 0B2603CP is a Quick Charge 3.0 negotiation chip. Here are the photos:
[image: 0B2603CP]

[image: 0B2004ZCP]

Comment: Search for OB not 0B, e.g. this seems to match the first one: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Battery-Management-ICs_OB-On-Bright-Elec-OB2603BCPA_C138863.html

Comment: Thanks @Mat. It's the exact same part.